# What is the correct response for a question mark?

Tags: usage, questions

People regularly respond to my messages with single question marks.  They do not use their words, so I do not use mine, and I do not think anyone has ever followed up.  Does it just mean "This is a response, la-la-la-la, Elmos's response?"  Thank you very much!

Comment: It's an equivalent of making quizzical expression IRL.

Comment: Please give an example of the exchange, without context it is difficult to say what is going on. Usually "?" = "What?" and can mean the receiver does;t understand what you mean.

Comment: Personally, I hate it when people do that, precisely because it's so vague.  It means they're questioning something.  *What* they're questioning, or why, is left completely unclear.  So there is no obvious correct response.

Comment: The correct response to "**?**" is "**%&#$£§!!**"

Answer (score 1):

Some possible correct responses for "**?**" might be

> Did you understand?
>   What don't you understand?

or possibly even

> ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Sorry to abandon you all of these years!  How have you been? :)
I tried responding "What part don't you understand?" several times and they never specified anything, just giving a one-word answer, so I moved on.
My sisters usually react to my text messages and I don't care what they think italicizing it means.